# javascript sort with no multiple entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Here is my code

```js
var array1 = [1,1, 30, 4, 21];
array1.sort();
console.log(array1);
// expected output: Array [1, 21, 30, 4]
```

I want to get the result [1,4,21,30]. the sort function should have give expected result [1,1,4,21,30] it is not giving that . Furthermore what approaches should i take just to keep one "1"? as I dont want duplications

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Comment: [Get all unique values in an array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-an-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `sort` you can `filter` your array to get rid of duplicates.

Here

```js
var array1 = [1,1, 30, 4, 21];
array1.sort((a, b) => a - b);
var s = array1.filter(function(i, o) {
    return array1.indexOf(i) == o;
});

console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can combine `sort()` and `reduce()` just take in considiration that `includes` do not work in IE and as you can see in the snippet below the statement

```
a.includes(x) ? a : [...a, x]
```

represent an if statement to get rid of the duplicate element and return a single value of each element

```js
var array1 = [1,1, 30, 4, 21];
var sortedArray1 = array1.reduce((a, x) => a.includes(x) ? a : [...a, x], []).sort()
console.log(sortedArray1);
// expected output: Array [1, 21, 30, 4]
```

Comment: can you please edit and explain this `a.includes(x) ? a : [...a, x]`

Comment: @brk it just inline if statement to remove the duplicate element

Comment: I got that but I just feel a bit of explanation will help others

Comment: @brk I did edit my answear , Thank you for your input

Answer (score 4):

## ES6

You can also use [`new Set([])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the [`Spread_syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
let arr= [1,1, 30, 4, 21];

arr = arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b);

console.log([...new Set(arr)])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort` and `filter` at the same time. First using `sort` with condition `a>b` will give you an array with ascending values with duplicates and using `filter` will remove the duplicates from the sorted array.

```js
var array1 = [1,1, 30, 4, 21];
function sort_unique(arr) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => a>b).filter((el,i,a) => i==a.indexOf(el));
}
var res = sort_unique(array1);
console.log(res);
```

> I recommend to use `indexOf()` as `includes()` do not work in IE
>   browsers

Answer (score 1):

After short just try to filter uniqueValues

```
var array1 = [1,1, 30, 4, 21];
array1.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
var uniqueValues = [];


 $.each(array1, function(i, el){
        if($.inArray(el, uniqueValues) === -1) uniqueValues.push(el);
    });

console.log(uniqueValues);
```

[Result Here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNNRp.jpg)